# How to use fastlane's "produce" in Fastfile to enable push notifications?

Tags: ios, fastlane

I'd like to add to Fastfile action that enables push notifications. In CLI I would run `produce enable_services -a com.example.app --push-notification`. How do I do that in a Fastfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it is possible through the [modify_services](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/modify_services/) action.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/fastlane/produce/issues/81#issuecomment-148947513 the only way for now is
`sh "produce enable_services --healthkit"`